# How to iterate a re.search function over columns

Tags: python, pandas, search

I have a df that looks similar to the below but with 100s of columns, where each column references a different text resolution.

| Index | A/RES/73/262 | A/RES/73/263 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Issue | NaN | HR |
| Description | Protection of the Palestinian civilian | Situation of human rights in Myanmar |

The "Issue" row contains mostly NaN values but occasionally has "HR" manually filled in for when "human rights" are mentioned in the description.

I would like to automate filling values in the "Issue" row process for a series of general terms using re.search. I am trying to figure out how to iterate my function over columns so that whenever a match is found for a column in the description cell, the value in the Issue code is changed according to a dictionary. However, I am having trouble with getting the for loop correct.

Below is the code I am working with so far. However, I get TypeErrors: expected string or bytes-like object since I am not passing a list of strings but a set of columns.

```
issue_dict = {'human rights':'HR', 'nuclear':'NU', 'sustainable development':'SD'}

for (columnName, columnData) in issues_df.iteritems():
    for key in issue_dict.keys():      
        search_keys = re.search(rf"(?i){key}", issues_df.iloc[[1]])
        if search_keys != None:
            issues_df = issues_df.replace({issues_df.iloc[[0]]: issue_dict})   
        else:
            issues_df.iloc[[0]] = pd.np.NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're over-complicating the use of `re.search`.
You could create a pattern from your dictionary keys, then look for this pattern and set the `Issue` row accordingly:

```
issue_dict = {'human rights':'HR', 'nuclear':'NU', 'sustainable development':'SD'}
key_pattern = re.compile(rf'({"|".join(issue_dict.keys())})')

for columnName, columnData in issues_df.iteritems():
    matched_key = re.search(key_pattern, columnData[1])
    if matched_key:
        columnData[0] = issue_dict.get(matched_key.group(), pd.np.NaN)
    else:
        columnData[0] = pd.np.NaN

print(issues_df)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, it looks like your dataset would benefit from being transposed:

```
df.set_index('Index').T
```

output:

```
Index        Issue                             Description
A/RES/73/262   NaN  Protection of the Palestinian civilian
A/RES/73/263    HR    Situation of human rights in Myanmar
```

Then you can easily use your data as columns:

```
(df.set_index('Index').T
   .assign(Issue=lambda d: (d['Description'].str.contains('human rights')
                            .map({True: 'HR', False: float('nan')}))
          )
   #.T.reset_index() ## uncomment if you want the original wide format
)
```

output (long):

```
Index        Issue                             Description
A/RES/73/262   NaN  Protection of the Palestinian civilian
A/RES/73/263    HR    Situation of human rights in Myanmar
```

output (wide):

```
         Index                            A/RES/73/262                          A/RES/73/263
0        Issue                                     NaN                                    HR
1  Description  Protection of the Palestinian civilian  Situation of human rights in Myanmar
```